# Check if two values pointing to the same reference in an array

Tags: c#

Please in the following code, how can i check if num and num2 are pointing to the same reference in myArray and skip to the next instance of j if they are.

I tried if `(myArray[i] == myArray[j])`, but it returns true if there is another item in the array with the same value. Thanks!

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
{
    int num = myArray[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < myArray.Length; j++)
    {
        int num2;
        if (myArray[i] == myArray[j])
        {

        }
        else
        {
            num2 = myArray[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An array of integer doesn't contain any kind of _reference_. Please explain what do you think is a reference.

Comment: I mean if the variable num assigned to myArray[i] is pointing to the same memory as myArray[j]

Comment: Since the variable `num` is a value type, not a reference, it is stored in memory on the stack, not on the heap, and therefore the only variable in the code that uses that same memory (on the stack frame for the specific method where `num` is declared), is indeed, `num` and **ONLY** `num`. No other variable points to that memory.

Comment: Then you should check the indexes of the two loops. If the indexer of the first loop has the same value of the indexer of the second loop then you are looking at the same value in the same position inside the same array. Do not use the term _reference_ because this has a total different meaning-

Answer (score -3, accepted):

if i==j then they are the same 'reference'.

To be more clear:

if i==j then myArray[i] and myArray[j] are referencing the same element.

Comment: i implemented this in my code and it worked, thanks.                     if (i==j)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

Comment: No they are not, they are the same **value**. That may indeed be all the op is really concerned about, but as this issue is source of significant confusion for beginning .Net coders, leaving this as accepted answer, uncommented, would be a disservice.

Comment: Agreed it was what the op was trying to get at, but used the incorrect terms.  However since he was indexing into the same array with 2 different indexers, he was attempting to reference the same element of the same array.

Comment: @NebulaSleuth, In fact, reading your answer again, I apologize, Mentally, I initially saw values being compared, not indices. It might have been clearer if you had written `if array indices are the same (i==j) then ...`. But your answer is correct.

Comment: @CharlesBretana... I will edit the answer to be more clear for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

Since the variable `num` is a value type, not a reference, it is stored in memory on the [stack, not on the heap](http://net-informations.com/faq/net/stack-heap.htm), and therefore the only variable in the code that uses that same memory (on the stack frame for the specific method where `num` is declared), is indeed, `num` and ***ONLY*** `num`. No other variable points to that memory.
Indeed, no other variable ***can*** point to that same memory.  even if you create a "boxed" reference variable based on `num`, that boxed version of `num` does *not* point to the same memory (*on the stack*) where `num` is, it will point to a copy of `num`, created on the *heap* at the point of code execution when the boxing occurs.

**Other Links**
[Stack and Heap](http://csharpcomputing.com/Tutorials/Lesson6.htm)
[Stack and Heap](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/c-sharp-heaping-vs-stacking-in-net-part-i/)

Comment: Labeling the difference between *value vs reference* types as *stack vs heap* memory is a bit misleading.  Value types can be stored on the heap, if they are the fields of a class (which is a reference type); otherwise they will go on the stack.  Reference types can never be on the stack.  The important part is that value types never have a sense of "reference equality", only "value equality", however reference types can be given custom `Equals` methods to make their equality comparisons behave like value comparisons (for example `String`).

Comment: Effectively, `Nullable<T>` is a struct with two fields, one of `T` called `Value` and one of `bool` called `HasValue`.  It is all value types, and the value of `HasValue` determine whether an exception is thrown when you try to access `Value`.

Comment: "Value types can be stored on the heap" ? NO.  a field of a instantiated class (an object) is not a value ***type***. What variable points to it? Yes, If you assign it's value to a *variable* in any method, that newly created variable is indeed a value type, but it is on the stack frame of the method. There is no variable pointing to the memory on the heap that contains the field's value. It can only be accessed using the instantiated object's reference variable, with the `[objectVariablename].fieldname]` syntax.

Comment: classifying a field as either a value, or a reference is about as meaningful as classifying a Property as value type or reference type; As we know, properties are implemented as methods (functions), and the actual data manipulated by that property getter and setter functions is stored on the heap regardless of whether the underlying type of the data is a mutable or an immutable primitive, or a pointer to another object on the heap.

Comment: `structs`, `enums` and the like are called "value types" as part of the standard C# terminology.  An `int` field is a field of a "value type", regardless of whether it is declared on a `struct` or `class`.  Whether that containing type is a `struct` or `class` will determine whether memory is allocated on the heap for the field.  When a field from a class is used in a calculation, that field's value will be copied to the stack, but the field is still on the heap.  For your second comment, it is the type of the member that determines value/reference, not the member.

Comment: structs,and enums ARE "value types" but they are stored on the stack, in the method's stack frame they are declared in, In fact, if you pass a struct to another method, it is copied (field by field) into a new struct in the called method's stack frame. And if you change their value in the called method the copy on the caller's stack is NOT changed, for exactly that reason. if you want the struct values in the caller to be mutable in the callee, then you have t opass it by ref, in which case a pointer to the memory in the caller's stack is passed to, and stored, in the callee's stack.

Comment: fields declared in a class are indeed stored on the heap, in the data  structure created for the instance of that class, but it is a bit of semantic misuse of the term to call them a value ***type***. the "value" stored in the field is indeed a primitive, not a pointer, but it is not a ***type*** at all, it is a ***method*** that fetches and sets that bit of memory in the objects data representation on the heap. Unlike every ***real*** type in the assembly, it does NOT have a CORINFO_CLASS_STRUCT, which every .Net ***Type*** must have, because, of course, it is not a type.

Comment: check out https://books.google.com/books?id=Kl1DVZ8wTqcC&pg=PA167&lpg=PA167&dq=CORINFO_CLASS&source=bl&ots=5c6NzzRLUS&sig=gbaxHS3nOHGBggscGKzKXAEd2Rg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjz3s-tm_zQAhVO6GMKHW5VCFYQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=CORINFO_CLASS&f=false for more info. Every type defined in an assembl;y gets one of these COR_INFO_CLASS_STRUCTs, Fields, properties and methods, otoh, just get an entry in the COR_INFO_CLASS_STRUCTs vTable.

Answer (score 1):

For checking refference equality you need to use Object.ReferenceEquals method. Simple equal operators (==) also works but only between refference types if equality isn't overriden.

In your case you can only check references between two arrays but not inside values. Your arrays contains integer values which are value types.

Answer (score 0):

As [**Steve**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197518/steve) said; you'll need to explain what you think is a reference. And if you want to just continue if the statement is true; you can simply use the `continue;` function.